# How to render ONLY the bounding box?

Tags: rendering

I need to render the bounding box of a number of objects in an animation. This is both for a specific effect, and hopefully, to speed up rendering. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: More context would get you better answers sooner. What kind of objects? How are they animated? How do you want the bounding boxes to look? You could provide some screenshots of what you have and some examples of your desired results in pictures so it's instantly clear without too much writing. I believe people will hesitate providing answers because the question is quite vague at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

You could add a very simple Geometry Nodes setup to your objects:

[image]

It's possible to change materials in Geometry Nodes as well if that's something that is desired.

Comment: Oh, once again I was too late with my answer and overlooked the fact that someone had already written something :D

Comment: I am sometimes quick with the simplest ones. :D

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Geometry Nodes modifier to replace certain objects with a bounding box.

This can also be set up so that the bounding box is only used when rendering and you can also add a checkbox to control this per object.

Something like this:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 4.0.2+)*</sub>

Comment: **Note to self:** ...when I think about it, this answer makes no sense at all, because you could simply deactivate the modifier! ...Haha, once again thinking too complicated :D (but the viewport-check is useful in this case)